# inside Iframe, Youtube player unmute function stops working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Before flagging this as duplicate please read the details.

I have the youtube player autoplays MUTED inside an iframe and have an unmute button and I am calling unMute() on pressing the button. However I get this error:

Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

this is the player code :

```
try {
      new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: this.config.mediaId,
        playerVars: {
          modestbranding : 1,
          rel : 0,
          showinfo : 0,
          autoplay: 1,
          color: 'white',
          rel: 0,
          playsinline: 1,
          controls: 0
        },
        events: {
          onReady: this.onPlayerReady.bind(this)
        }
      });
    } catch(e) {
      showErrorScreen(e);
    }

onPlayerReady(event) {
    this.playerRef = event.target;
    this.playerRef.mute();
    this.playerRef.playVideo(); // because autoplay: 1 sometimes does not work

  }

...
const unmute = (event) => {
    playerRef.unMute();
    state.muted = false;
    updateVolumeControls();
  };
```

Here the link to the page:

https://video.inpwrd.net/college-prep-dont-go-it-alone/48ebe783-bcc4-4b96-9ba5-aff3db5f13df

Outside iframe it works. This is definitely a bug in youtube player code. I am sticking to autoplay muted policy. I believe they have this assumption that the player is always in the root document. This is the stack trace:

Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

```
g.h.xk  @   base.js:6951
jya @   base.js:4586
yQ  @   base.js:4585
Fna @   base.js:3091
g.h.unMute  @   base.js:6718
a.F.(anonymous function)    @   base.js:3082
g.h.handleExternalCall  @   base.js:6698
a.C.(anonymous function)    @   base.js:3086
(anonymous) @   www-embed-player.js:526
k.la    @   www-embed-player.js:609
k.La    @   www-embed-player.js:598
ii.B    @   www-embed-player.js:594
```

Please don't give hacky solutions that work today and stop working tomorrow.

Comment: allow="autoplay; fullscreen" on iframe fixed it https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-feature-policy/#allowlist

Answer (score 2):

allow="autoplay; fullscreen" on iframe fixed it w3c.github.io/webappsec-feature-policy/#allowlist –

Comment: In my case the `autoplay` value alone was sufficient, I tested it with a chrome guest profile to avoid false positives from EMI.